# relations and equivalence classes

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

$S$ is the set of all equivalence relations on set $A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ in which one of the  equivalence classes is $\{1,3,5,7,9\}$. What is the size of $S$?

I don't even know how to start...
Detailed explanation will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I think the purpose of this question is to find all possible partitions of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ that have $\{1,3,5,7,9\}$ as member. E.g. a partition could be $\{\{1,3,5,7,9\},\{2,4\},\{6\},\{8\}\}$.

Comment: In other words, you can just [count the partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set#Counting_partitions) of {2,4,6,8}.